# Google Cloud Datastore and reports/administration

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm quite new to Google App Engine and it's cloud Datastore which is used for storing the backend's data by default. As far as I realized you can only view it's content within the developer console and you can create or edit entities there.

But is there any external tool from which you can connect to your datastore to create reports or administer the data? What is your experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact yes it's true you can only see data's from the admin console.

If you wish to see your data's in Google Drive Table and make a report you can, but for that you need to create a connector to your sheet (I already made one). It's exactly the same if you need update or import data's to your datastore.
I use this Technic to upload or refresh products on my e-shop GAE app.

In general if I need to see a report, I design a specific web page for that and I protect theme via a login / password. To see a well formatted report you can use jquery library or use [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery?hl=fr)

Comment: How do you create such a connector to Google Drive? Any documentation?

Comment: You need to publish your Google spreadsheet as a web app and use **doPost** or **doGet** to receive data's. You can also use the GAS Class **UrlFetchApp** to get data's via an http call to your GAE app. If you need to send a lot of data's from your GAE app, the best practice is to use a task. [simple tutorial to use doPost or soGet](http://blog.eforcers.com/2012/08/building-google-apps-script-web-app.html) [Google Apps Script UrlFetchApp documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app?csw=1)